# php array_search single array with multiple hits

Tags: php, arrays

I'm doing a calendar with possibly more than 1 event matching the date each day.  Currently I'm puzzled as how to discover more than the first match with array_search.  Here is what I'm doing right now.

```
if (array_search($date_today, $event_start) !== FALSE ) {
     $date_match = array_search($date_today, $event_start);
     $name       = $event_name[$date_match];    
   }
```

Can I advance the array_search with a 'while' or 'for each' statement to find multiple matches?  In case it's important my date variables are dates like 1368680400.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Documentation for array_search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) tells us:

> If needle is found in haystack more than once, the first matching key
>   is returned. To return the keys for all matching values, use
>   array_keys() with the optional search_value parameter instead.